# R osmdata query returns object contaminated with results from an old query

Tags: r, openstreetmap, spatial, r-sf

I have made the following query using the osmdata package:

```
library(osmdata)
library(sf)

# Get map boundaries for UK:
bb <- getbb ('uk', format_out = 'polygon')

# Fetch data for selected boundaries from osmdata:
ukbasemap <- opq(bbox = bb) %>% # set boundary box
  add_osm_feature(key = 'admin_level', value = '4') %>% # add feature
  osmdata_sf () %>% # convert to sf object
  trim_osmdata (bb) # trim to edges of boundary (i.e. UK borders)
```

This returned the following warning, but otherwise created the sf object without apparent issue:
`bb_poly has more than one polygon; the first will be selected.`

I then tried to plot the data, but the below code produces a blank plot:

```
> sf::plot_sf(ukbasemap$osm_lines)
> sf::plot_sf(ukbasemap$osm_polygons)
> sf::plot_sf(ukbasemap$osm_multipolygons)
> sf::plot_sf(ukbasemap$osm_points)
```

When I inspected the sf object, I was surprised to see some place names from Central African Republic in it.  I ran a query for CAR a few months ago, and the only thing I can think of is that I accidentally set some global options to refer to CAR data - but I don't remember doing that.  Here is a snippet of what the sf object looks like:

```
> ukbasemap$osm_points
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 23 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 20.54475 ymin: 5.768001 xmax: 20.67557 ymax: 6.311055
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
               osm_id    name   GNS.id alt_name capital created_by  ele ford is_in.continent
2222388003 2222388003   Ouaka     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA>            <NA>
4680378478 4680378478 Bambari -1339188     <NA>       4       <NA> <NA> <NA>            <NA>
           is_in.country name.de name.en   name.ko  name.ru name.sg  name.uk place
2222388003          <NA>    <NA>    <NA>      <NA> Ð£Ð°ÐºÐ°  WÃ¤kÃ¤ Ð£Ð°ÐºÐ° state
4680378478          <NA>    <NA>    <NA> ë°¤ë°”ë¦¬     <NA>    <NA>     <NA>  city
           population  ref source state_code wikidata wikipedia                  geometry
2222388003       <NA>   UK   <NA>         UK  Q848560  fr:Ouaka POINT (20.54475 6.311055)
4680378478      41356 <NA>    GNS       <NA>  Q805946      <NA> POINT (20.67557 5.768001)
```

"Ouaka" and "Bambari" are place names in Central African Republic.

Does anyone know what could be going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'd suspect that your bounding box is wrong. Usually, requests for countries via `getbb` do not work.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how it could have confused "UK" with "Central African Republic" though... is there something more accurate than `getbb()` that you could suggest for the boundary box? Also would be interested to know if other people get the same when running this code (because that would eliminate the possibility that it is getting mixed up with an old query).

Comment: I have no idea for why it goes to a place in CAR, and I usually do is that I download a shapefile rather than using getbb for countries. Or you can manually get the bounding box.

Comment: I do get the same output as yours.

Comment: Your question made me realize it was actually possible to get the bb for a country, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your bounding box does not actually refer to the United Kingdom. It is the case because the default `featuretype = "settlement"` combines results from all intermediate levels below "country" and above "streets" (see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/osmdata/man/getbb.html)).

You can get the bounding box for a country by adding `feature_type = "country"`.

```
bb <- getbb("uk", format_out = 'polygon', featuretype = "country")
```

You can check whether your bounding box is correct by mapping it like this.

```
library(leaflet)

bb <- getbb("uk", format_out = 'sf_polygon', featuretype = "country")

leaflet(bb$multipolygon) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolygons()
```

[image: UK map]

While with `bb <- getbb ('uk', format_out = 'polygon')`, you get:

[image]